# no device ready event received in ionic serve

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Platform: ionic 3

I find that no device ready event received when using `ionic serve`.
But there is the event with emulator.

Checking:

```
this.renderer.listen('document', 'deviceready', () => {
      console.log("device ready");
    });
```

The reason why I need the event is because a plugin starts after that event.
And I want to test the app using browser to save development time.
Is there any way to get the event using `ionic serve`?
I had a project that can init a node module listening `deviceready`. The problem is I don't know the config to do that. 
Maybe I can fire the event manually?

Details:
cordova-plugin-mfp - bootstrap.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', loadMFP, false); 
function loadMFP(){
  if(typeof WL !== 'undefined' && WL.StaticAppProps){
    mfpready();
  }
}
```

Comment: To use `cordova-plugin-mfp` plugin you should use real device or emulator, you can't do it with browser.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda yes, normally we should use native platform to test. However, i had a project previously that can init `cordova-plugin-mfp` using ionic serve. The problem is i don't know what config exactly done on the project.